# Angular Universal - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am building an Angular Universal application by going through [this documentation](https://codeburst.io/angular-server-side-rendering-using-angular-cli-bbde0c0eefe9). But now I've integrated a third party app [`angular2-multiselect-dropdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown) in my application. When I serve the application locally it works well, but when I serve it on node server it throws:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

I also tried many solutions given [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/581#issuecomment-326256510), but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular are you using?

If using webpack, try whitelisting that module in your webpack config

```
//webpack.server.js

target: 'node',
externals: [nodeExternals({
 whitelist: [
  /^angular2-multiselect-dropdown/
 ]
})],
```

Comment: I am using angular5 and not using webpack.